# round towards zero in java

Tags: java

How to round in java towards zero?

So  -1.9  becomes -1.0 and -0.2 becomes 0.0, 3.4 becomes 3.0 and so on.

Is `Math.round()` capable of doing this changing some parameters?

Comment: `x-x%1` (in Java only)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I do not believe that the standard library has such a function.

The problem is that you are asking for very different behavior (mathematically speaking) depending on whether the number is larger or smaller than 0 (i.e. rounding up for negative values, rounding down for positive values)

The following method could be used:

```
public double myRound(double val) {
    if (val < 0) {
        return Math.ceil(val);
    }
    return Math.floor(val);
}
```

Comment: +1: The only answer so far which does the right thing (AFAICS).

Answer (score 10):

cast to long like this:

```
float x= 1.9;

long y = (long)x;
```

This rounds both positive and negative numbers towards zero.

Comment: Provided the result fits in an `int`, which may be a big if

Comment: Why would you cast to an `int` and store it in a `long`? Cast to a `long`.

Comment: **-1:** this fails in cases where the floating point number is too big or too small to be represented by a 64 bit integer. Whether `int` or `long`, the problem is only shifted. Such numbers may not be common in everyday usage – but that only makes it more difficult to find bugs related to over/underflow.

Answer (score 7):

Use `RoundingMode.DOWN`, it leads towards zero.

Example :

```
    BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("1.4");
    value = value.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN);
    System.out.println(value.doubleValue());
    BigDecimal value1 = new BigDecimal("-1.4");
    value1 = value1.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN);
    System.out.println(value1.doubleValue());
```

Comment: Can a `BigDecimal` represent all the values that a `float` or `double` can represent?

Comment: BigDecimal is the way to represent a number in java, so it makes sense to use BigDecimal

Comment: @Oli Yes. BigDecimal is an arbitrary precision decimal, it can represent all the values a float and double can and more.

Comment: @mprabhat `BigDecimal` isn't '*the* way to represent a number in Java'. It is one among several.

Comment: It certainly is overkill, especially when a primitive will do just fine.

Answer (score 5):

Just casting to int will do that for you?

Edit: If you want to retain a double this should work simply enough:

```
if (val < 0) 
   return -Math.floor(-val);
else
   return Math.floor(val);
```

And just for the people who want branch free code and feel a bit more clever:

```
long tmp = Double.doubleToLongBits(val);
tmp >>>= 63;
return Math.floor(val) + tmp;
```

Comment: Provided the result fits in an `int`, which may be a big if.

Comment: @aix True enough, but then you also can't guarantee that there exists a double that can represent the number. But yes that's nitpicking on my side ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
y=sign(x)*floor(abs(x))
```

or

```
y=sign(x)*round(abs(x)-0.5)
```

It should be easy to implement in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to always round-down? You can use `Math.floor` instead

> `public static double floor(double a)`
>
> Returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) double value that
>   is not greater than the argument and is equal to a mathematical
>   integer. Special cases:

Comment: `Math.floor()` rounds towards -ve infinity, not zero.

Answer (score 0):

`BigDecimal` offers many [rounding options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html).

Comment: In particular, that would be DOWN to solve the OP's need which is different from FLOOR in that FLOOR follows the correct mathematical behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You also can try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double myDouble = -3.2;
        System.out.println(myDouble.intValue()); //Prints -3

    }
```